# Google Data Studio - automatic file upload

Tags: looker-studio

Is there any possibility of automatic files upload (csv) to Google Data Studio, for example, daily? 
Unfortunately, uploading files by Google Sheets is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to automatically upload csv files to Data Studio.

However, if you can upload the csv file to any publicly accessible website, you can write a [community connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) to fetch data from that specific file every time the report is opened or refreshed. This can work with:

- Constant file names (e.g. *www.example.com/my_data.csv*)
- File names with a specific pattern (e.g. *www.example.com/my_data-{sequential_number}.csv* or *www.example.com/{date}_my_data.csv*)

Comment: If the file is not large and the source is public it's possible use IMPORTDATA and Google Sheets Connector